# How to Handle a Long Description Line For Interface Function

Tags: c#, function

I got a long description for my interface function.

**IMyInterface.cs**

```
[Description("Line 1 description content here! Line 2 description content here!Line 3  description content here!Line 4 description content here!Line 5 description content here!Line 6 description content here!")]
void foo()
{
}
```

How to convert the single line to multi lines style. thanks.

```
[Description("Line 1 description content here! 
 Line 2 description content here!Line 3 description content here!
 Line 4 description content here!Line 5 description content here!
 Line 6 description content here!")]
void foo()
{
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use a verbatim string, just preppend @ to your string:

```
[Description(@"Line 1 description content here!  
 Line 2 description content here!
 Line 3 description content here! 
 Line 4 description content here!
 Line 5 description content here! 
 Line 6 description content here!")] 
void foo() 
{ 
}
```

Note that the indentations starting on line 2 will be part of your string in this case.

Comment: Hi Jordao, With your help, I googled **@** and found: C# has another type of string -- the string literal (@"")... Thanks.